# copying a cell from one table to another in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How do you go about copying a cell from one table to another using mysql and php
reason i asked is I have two tables payment and payment history, payment stores the values of the last payment and shows what is currently owed however payment history stores all the payment transactions made and the amount owed after each transaction therefore the main reason i need it is to show the various amounts owed in respect to the payments, so for payment table i would use an update query and for payment history I use an insert query

Comment: So what is the question again? looks like you have the answer already.

Comment: I need to know how to copy a single cell from one table to another..example a payment is made, amount owed is now $100, I want this amout to be in the payment history, payment two is made amount owed is $50 i want this to be a new record in the payment history table so therefore row one would have amount owed=$100, and row two would show amount owed is $50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to INSERT into a table from another table you can use:

```
INSERT INTO TableBar (column1, column2 )
SELECT TableFoo.column1, TableFoo.column2 
FROM TableFoo
WHERE <<YOUR CLAUSE HERE>>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to insert

```
insert into myTable (field1, field2) 
select from myotherTable where somefield = "something";
```

if you need to simply update

```
update myTable set field1 = 
(select field1Equivalent from otherTAble where someField="something");
```

Comment: THis seems to be able to do the trick I will check and let you know the Results Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a trigger, just update the table1 and table2 will get the new record.

You'll have to do something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggername AFTER INSERT ON table1
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2 ) VALUES (OLD.value1, OLD.value2);
  END;
```